# Connect local ReactionCommerce app with remote database

Tags: meteor, configuration, reaction-commerce

How can I connect my local running reaction app with a remote mongodb?

I tried creating this settings.json file

```
{
    "env" : {
        "MONGO_URL" : "<remote db url >"
    }
}
```

And ran the app with this command

```
meteor run --inspect-brk --settings settings.json
```

But it still connects to local meteor mongo. Could someone tell me the correct syntax to configure mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `.env` file at the root of your `reaction` directory, defining `MONGO_URL` (and any other environment variable you may need) this way:

```
MONGO_URL=<MongoDB URL>
```

Comment: Hi @Load, does the .env have to used as an argument in the app running script?
Eg : meteor run -e app.env

Comment: It is taken into account automatically, provided that it's named `.env` and is placed inside your root Reaction back-end directory.

Comment: @ShabinMuhammed If I helped you, could you please mark the answer as correct? Otherwise, let me know how I can help further.

Comment: I'll be getting back to this project in a couple of days. Will try out and let you know the results.